# pandas data frame mismatch type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My problem is a mismatch of floats and integers. My goal is to have

```
123.002
1
12
123.0
```

And make it

```
123.002
1.000
12.000
123.000
```

I tried using coerce but I ended up with

```
123.000
1.000
12.000
123.000
```

Comment: Thank you for the formatting update

Answer (score 0):

Coercing errors shouldn't be necessary, unless you have non-numeric strings somewhere in the column.

```
df
         a
0  123.002
1        1
2       12
3    123.0

df.dtypes
 
a    object
dtype: object

pd.to_numeric(df['a'])

0    123.002
1      1.000
2     12.000
3    123.000
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

This is with coercion:

```
df

         a
0  123.002
1        1
2       12
3    123.0
4        A

pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors="coerce")
 
0    123.002
1      1.000
2     12.000
3    123.000
4        NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```